# Can't access to public IP of django docker container

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2

I can access the container with these curl commands:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/health/
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/health/
```

But I can't access it with public IP address:

```
curl http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/api/health/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xx.xxx.xxx port 8000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

I used this command to run the container:

```
docker container run -d --network=host -p 8000:8000 my-central-api
```

Dockerfile has this line:

```
CMD [ "python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I am running this container on an EC2 instance. I set up the security group and NACL. So I think it is related to docker configuration.

Why I can't access to port 8000 with public IP?

Comment: It might be a Firewall/Port Issue or the Router isn't *bouncing* the traffic back. Can you access it **off** the network?- like on your cellphone using cellular? (That's how i always test things like this)

Comment: Are you allowed IP in django config settings ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru I didn't configured django for any IP address.

Comment: I added public IP address to ALLOWED_HOSTS. I still have the same problem.

Comment: i am not so much xp with container, but shouldn't we add a route between the ip and the container?